# How do I access elements having the same id, name, class etc. in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have a set of drop-down elements on my page and all they have the same id, name, class, etc. How do I access a particular element using WebDriver (Java) without using xpath locator?

Plz give me solution

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Can you please share ur htm code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findElemets()` method that returns you a list of found objects. Then you just take the item you currently need like:

```
List<WebElement> dropDowns = driver.findElements(By.name("NAME_OF_DROPDOWN"));
WebElement dropDown = dropDowns.get(INDEX_OF_ELEMENT_YOU_NEED);
```

This is the example on how you can access elements without using xpath.